# Loading a json file into DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This javaScript code works great when I execute it with Node using a local file, but now when I run this at the command line I get "Undefined:1".

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const http = require("http");

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

//cron(0 18 ? * MON-FRI *)
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing Work Orders into DynamoDB Jobs table. Please wait.");

http.get('http://www.MyWebSite.com/Data/WOjson/02152018.json', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

console.log("Now it is time to parse the file.");

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';

res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
res.on('end', () => {
  });
const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

parsedData.forEach(function(job) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "Jobs",
        Item: {
            "userId":  job.userId,
            "WorkOrder": job.WorkOrder,
            "ServiceDate":  job.ServiceDate,
            "JobType": job.JobType
        }
    };

// Here is where I post to the DynamoDB table
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add job", job.WorkOrder, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", job.WorkOrder);
       }
    });
});


}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

**I have updated the code to use http.**  I do get the console log message, "Now it is time to parse the file.", but then I get the message "Undefined:1" and no items go into my DynamoDB table.

```
res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
res.on('end', () => {
  });
const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

parsedData.forEach(function(job) {
```

Ideally, I'd like to execute this lambda function on a schedule (once a day at say 6pm) to read a remote file into my DynamoDB table.

Comment: the second argument to readFileSync is an object so it should be `{encoding: "utf8"}` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options  You could also try splitting that apart from the JSON.parse to ensure that is the part causing the problem.

Comment: @JarredOlson - Got rid of the `fs` as it didn't appear to work with the remote file.  I also did split the two read apart to isolate the issue, but I still got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not worked with the `fs` API that much, but I don't think it's ideal for your use-case, as I think it deals with the local(relative to the server) filesystem and not remote. Theoretically, AWS provides access to the `/tmp` folder which I think would be ephemeral so I don't think it's a good place to store data either.
For your use case, there are 2 ways I can think of handling the same:

1. Bundle up a module that handles http requests(e.g request module), which you can then use to interact with the remote files, when it's on the Lambda, essentially it would go like:

```js
if(process.env.USE_REMOTE_FS) {
  const request = require('request');
  // use request module
  // async/await or turn to a promise
  request.get('http://www.MyWebSite.com/Data/WOjson/02152018.json',...)
  ...
} else {
  const fs = require('fs');
  // use fs module
  ...
}
```

2. Bundle up a module that handles the details for you. In Ruby, there's the open-uri Gem, I think a similar one exists for node [open-uri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-uri), which can do a similar thing based on the uri passed in.
   This would go like:

```js
const open = require('open-uri');
// you can async/await or turn this to a promise
open(uri, function(err, jsonData) { JSON.parse(jsonData) });
```

You can also use the low-level `http` module instead of the request module, if you don't want to deal with excessive function administration and deploys.

### Update 1

I just checked the documentation for fs and it appears [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) should work, however you should provide a [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) object, so essentially I'd imagine you first creating your URL and pass it to fs. Personally, I'd prefer the `open-uri` option though because it abstracts a lot of these details.

### Update 2

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.MyWebSite.com/Data/WOjson/02152018.json', (res) => {
  // deal with your status code etc here
  ...

  let data = '';

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk; // append chunk to data
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    // this is where the rest of your code could be called. there are several approaches to calling here, either abstracting the remaining work to a function and pass in the data or wrapping the http call with a promise etc. For now, let's log the data
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log( parsedData );
    ...
    parsedData.forEach(...)
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error occured: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get the fs to work and so I tried the `http` module, but I'm getting this "Undefined:1" message.

Comment: I think you're probably using the http/fs module wrongly, updated the answer to include the right approach to using the http[s] module. Addiitonally, I'd advise that you check that the data that you're pulling is also correct.

Comment: Also, more generally rather than changing the question entirely with an updated approach, I'd advise that you create `Update` subsections as that helps to gain more context into what you asked, what you've done and what needs to be done